# CodeIgniter view only outputting single character from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to output strings to form an image path, the strings are held in a nested array at the deepest level.

My loop iterates over all array contents at this level but only outputs the first letter from the array content and I cant figure out why.

So I need a bit of help, here's what I have...

Array dump:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [p_name] => Shops
        [p_startdate] => foo
        [p_enddate] => bar
        [p_elapsed] => hello
        [p_rag] => Array
            (
                [0] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [1] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [2] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [3] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [4] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [5] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [6] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [7] => grayNodePng6160.png
                [8] => grayNodePng6160.png
            )

        )

)
```

Controller index method

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();

    $data['splash_projects'] = $this->generate_projects();

    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('include/navigation');
    $this->load->view('splash', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

Controller helper method:

```
    private function generate_projects(){

    $projects = array(
        array (
            "p_name"      => "Shops",
            "p_startdate" => "foo",
            "p_enddate"   => "bar",
            "p_elapsed"   => "hello",
            "p_rag"       => array ('grayNodePng6160.png', 'grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png',
                'grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png','grayNodePng6160.png')
        )
    );

return $projects;   
}
```

View:

```
    <?php if($splash_projects!==false):?>
    <?php foreach ($splash_projects as $sproject):?>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="section-paragraph">Project Name :<?php echo $sproject['p_name']?></p>
                <p class="section-paragraph">Start Date: <?php echo $sproject['p_startdate']?></p>
                <p class="section-paragraph">End Date: <?php echo $sproject['p_enddate']?></p>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($sproject['p_rag'] as $rag):?>
                    <?php $x=0 ?>                   
                        <li><img class="section-paragraph">Overview: <?php echo $rag[$x] ?></img></li>                  
                    <?php endforeach?>
                </ul>             
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach?>
<?php endif?>
```

This is the output - Overview: g, I get this line printed once for each element in the array.

The full path info isn't there yet I'm just trying to get the dynamic data out first.

Can anybody help? Many Thanks.

Comment: I don't see your view being loaded, so I can only assume so much, but are you actually passing your data to the view and are you doing anything with it before it gets ther? I don't doubt it just making sure. Also, what do you mean "first letter"? Honestly it's a pretty weird error IMHO. Anything in your logs?

Comment: Hi, the generate projects method is a helper to the index method which is generating the view, I've edted to add the code above but its pretty basic. The first letter is the "g" from grayNode1660.png I "think" it cant be anything else but every now and then php spits garbled nonsense at you but I dont think thats the case this time since its consistant with each echo in the loop. I'll check my logs next.

Comment: Yeah, check your logs and get back at me, that's honestly something bizarre IMHO. I'll keep looking and thinking. FYI, there are some other oddities in here too, but we can get to that after solving this problem :) Your loop looks ok given the array nesting, so the only thing I can think of is that when you are accessing your $rag variable in the foreach, you're actually accessing a single string, so $rag[0] would represent the first character.

Comment: Checked but there's nothing in the logs about it, I've never seen this before so bit of a pain! I'll keep fiddling but if you have an idea let me know, thanks for having a look.

Comment: We're gonna figure this thing out! I suspect the error is somewhere in your foreach nesting :) Can you var_dump $row inside the innermost foreach?

Comment: Nice one:) ok done a dump and we get this    string 'grayNodePng6160' (length=15) which is spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating $rag as an array instead of a string (which is what it is), so $rag[0] will return the first character in the string.

Why is that? If we think back to C we remember that a string is simply an array of char's, and this was carried over into PHP somewhat, so treating a string as an array is perfectly feasible :)

Comment: Thanks Zarazthuztra your absolutely right, I had thought this would give me the values at     $rag[n]...would you happen to know a nice way to do this?

Comment: I'll have to think about that a whole lot more. At first glance your foreach loops make sense, so I'm clearly missing something (a missing semicolon error!!)

Comment: I'll keep chugging away, have a cup of tea on me :) thanks for your help man!

Comment: Absolutely dude! See if you can't figure this one out, because what you're doing makes perfect sense. I've GOT to be glossing over something obvious